# PropertyChanged doesnt work for binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, propertychanged

I've got a textbox which is filled by a property. When I click on the button the property value is changed and the textbox content should be changed too. However my property changed event doesn't work. I have already searched here and in other sources for a solution. I didn't find anything that could help. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestWPF {
    public class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        private string test = "test";
        public string TestProperty {
            get { return test; }
            set {
                if (value != test)
                    test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TestProperty");
            }
        }
    }
}

<Window.DataContext>
<local:Class1/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TestProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-100,0,0" Height="69" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="255"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Edit:

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        cs1.TestProperty = "Test button";
    }
```

Comment: `cs1` (i guess it is an instance of `Class1`) != `Window.DataContext`; window is bound to another context

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
        var dc = (sender as System.Windows.Controls.Button).DataContext;
        var cs1 = dc as Class1;
        cs1.TestProperty = "Test button";
}
```

or

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Class1 cs1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = cs1 = new Class1();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
       cs1.TestProperty = "Test button";
    }
}
```

And without:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:Class1/>
</Window.DataContext>
```